# Algorithm to match time control preferences in a chess game

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have two chess players with the following time control preferences in order, top are most desirable, below - least (45 45 for example means 45 mins per game + 45 s per move) for example:

```
   Player A                   Player B
    45 45                      90 30   
    90 30                      120 30
    50 10                      45 45  
   120 30
```

what generalized algorithm to use to choose the time control that would maximally suit both players?

Comment: It would depend on just how much more a player prefers a time control preference over another. How are you going to measure that?

Comment: As I understand some cost function should be used to compute for example the "desirability" of 45 45. And if there is a tie between some controls then choose randomly or something else. The problem is the cost function.

Comment: Some people really really like their first choice, but some other people like all their choices the same. This information is not currently available, so an algorithm cannot be made.

Comment: Is the solution space discrete, i.e. does the selected preference have to be in one of the lists (preferably both) or can we take, for example, means of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is strange how I did not figure it out at first.

Let A be a set of all time controls player A accepts, and B for player B, respectively. Let S be an intersection of sets A and B - it is the time controls both players willing to play.

So we have to find x in set S, so that

```
i + j -> min
```

where i is index of preference x for player A, and j is index of preference x for player B (for example 45 45: i = 1, j = 3).

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the solution space is discrete and the selected preference does indeed have to be in one of the lists (preferably both), I suggest the following approach:

Each player weights their preferences with values `0 <= w_p <= 1` such that for each player all values `w_p` sum up to 1 (higher weight = higher preference).

Now there are several options for the objective function:

- `Utilitarian` Maximize the sum of the weights of the selected preference.
- `Social` Minimize the weight of the player with the lower weight of the selected preference.
- `Equalizing` Minimize the difference between the weights of the selected preference.

You probably should a priori exclude preferences for which not both player have a positive weight.